# Javascript local variables not appearing in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, debugging, local-variables

I am using Visual Studio 2010 to debug JavaScript. When I run the debugger my local variables window will show up at the bottom and will sometimes show locals for other files, but when I get to the file I need to debug it acts as if there are no local variables within the file.

I know there is a way to search for the locals within the window, but I cannot seem to find any instruction on how to do in on the web.  I would like for them to just show up as I debug instead of having to search for each one.

I saw a similar question asked and the only answer was to use a different IDE, but I do not have a choice, I must use VS2010.